# Moving AsyncTask to a new file

Tags: android

I created a new file for my AsyncTask, so I can break up my code into MVP.

File: **TranslateAddress.java**

```
public class TranslateAddress extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

final Dialog customDialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this); 

protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    customDialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_location_dialog);
    customDialog.setTitle("Looking for address");
    TextView text = (TextView) customDialog.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    text.setText("Looking for address");
    customDialog.show();

}

protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    Geocoder geocoder;
    List<Address> addresses = null;
    geocoder = new Geocoder(MainActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());
    if (geocoder != null) {
        try {
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1); // Here 1 represent max location result to returned, by documents it recommended 1 to 5
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0); // If any additional address line present than only, check with max available address lines by getMaxAddressLineIndex()
        city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
        state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
        country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
        postalCode = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
        knownName = addresses.get(0).getFeatureName(); // Only if available else return NULL
        // do download here
    } else {
        Log.e("Error", "Geocoder returned Null");
        MainActivity.OpenFragment("SolicitationFramgnet");
    }
    return null;
}

protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    //dialog.dismiss();
    customDialog.dismiss();
    EditText localText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.localText);
    if (localText != null) {
        localText.setText(address);
    }
}
}
```

These are the lines that have errors:

1. `final Dialog customDialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);`

**Error:** MainActivity is not an enclosing class

2. `geocoder = new Geocoder(MainActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());`

**Error:** Same as above, MainActivity is not an enclosing class

3. `MainActivity.OpenFragment("SolicitationFramgnet");`

**Error:** Non static method OpenFragment cannot be referenced from a static context. **This error I can fix by making OpenFragment static, however, it breaks half of the code inside it.**

4. `EditText localText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.localText);`

**Error:** Cannot resolve method "findViewById(int)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving your `AsyncTask` to another `.java` file you lose the reference of your `MainActivity` because before it functioned as an InnerClass and now it is just a Java Class, so you cannot use MainActivity methods or static context in this situation. Is the same thing for `findViewById` method because it belongs to your `Activity` and not to your  `AsyncTask`. To fix it you have to pass the context in your Constructor and the main layout so you can use `FindViewById` method inside your `TranslateAddress` file using this View (as a parameter of your constructor).

Something like this:

```
public class TranslateAddress extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

final Dialog customDialog;
private MainActivity mainActivity;
private View view;

public TranslateAddress(View view, MainActivity mainActivity){
    this.view = view;
    this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
}



protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();

    customDialog = new Dialog(mainActivity); 
    customDialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_location_dialog);
    customDialog.setTitle("Looking for address");
    TextView text = (TextView) customDialog.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    text.setText("Looking for address");
    customDialog.show();

}

protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    Geocoder geocoder;
    List<Address> addresses = null;
    geocoder = new Geocoder(mainActivity, Locale.getDefault());
    if (geocoder != null) {
        try {
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1); // Here 1 represent max location result to returned, by documents it recommended 1 to 5
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0); // If any additional address line present than only, check with max available address lines by getMaxAddressLineIndex()
        city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
        state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
        country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
        postalCode = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
        knownName = addresses.get(0).getFeatureName(); // Only if available else return NULL
        // do download here
    } else {
        Log.e("Error", "Geocoder returned Null");
       mainActivity.OpenFragment("SolicitationFramgnet");
    }
    return null;
}

protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    //dialog.dismiss();
    customDialog.dismiss();
    EditText localText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.localText);
    if (localText != null) {
        localText.setText(address);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, 2 things. 1) customDialog wasn't initialized, so I set `this.customDialog = new Dialog(context);` inside the method `public TranslateAddress(View view, Context context)`. 2) `(MainActivity)context.OpenFragment` returns an error, "**Cannot resolve method**".

Comment: I edit my answer. the customDialog works now  using this ?

Comment: There's no error, thanks for editing it. How would I go about executing it from the mainactivity though? Since when I do a `new TranslateAddress().execute` [I get this](http://i.imgur.com/udM47fu.png)

Comment: you have to create it first and then, do a execute method:  TranslateAddress ta  = new TranslateAddress(view, activity);
ta.execute();

Comment: That's precisely what I'm stuck on, "TranslateAddress(view, activity)". I don't know how to populate "view, activity".

Comment: The view is the layout for your MainActivity, you can get it in your activity code eg.  LinearLayout layout =(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.your_main_id); the activity is just `this`.

Answer (score 0):

For context, pass it from your MainActivity like this:

In AsyncTask, Create a constructor

```
Context context;
TranslateAddress(Context c){
    context = c;
}
```

Now use `context` instead of `MainActivity.this`. And execute AsyncTask from MainActivity as following:

```
new TranslateAddress(this).execute();
```

and for `findViewById()`, use following code:

```
context.findViewById("YOUR_ID");
```